# Can't access property in returned object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, struts

I've got a problem where I can't seem to query my JSON coming back, I can print out the entire response though, here's my JSON response, I can only see this when I do a `msgBox()` prompt:

```
{ "Addresses" : 
    "[{ 
        Building=Megatron Skyscraper,
        BuldingId=1998,
        AccountId=2000,
        Number=007,
        Name=Megatron 
        },{
        Building=StarScream Skyscraper,
        BuldingId=1999,
        AccountId=2001,
        Number=008,
        Name=StarScream
}]"}
```

And here's my code:

```
function getReadyStateHandler(req)
{
    // Return an anonymous function that listens to the
    // XMLHttpRequest instance
    return function ()
    {
        // If the request's status is "complete"
        if (req.readyState == 4)
        {
            // Check that a successful server response was received
            if (req.status == 200)
            {
                msgBox("JSON Response recieved...");
                var addresses = req.responseText.toJSON();
                msgBox(req.responseText.toJSON());
            }
            else
            {
                // An HTTP problem has occurred
                alert("HTTP error: " + req.status);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything from `addresses.Address[0].City` and `addressess.Addresses[0].City` and many others - but this is slightly confusing!

Comment: There is no `City` key in your object. And `Adresses` is a string for some reason. Even if you use `JSON.parse()` or `eval` it will not work as the sting is not valid for parsing. You have to make sure that you get a proper response first.

Comment: Hi, looks like everyone is correct, I've been doing: "response.getWriter().write(json.toString());" in my action - Do you know of a better way to handle this? I cant seem to do json.write() as I do not have a write() method for my JSONObject (which is strange!)

Comment: Also meant to state, my actual JSONResponse does contain City, this was just a quickly formed response example.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that there's no `City` key in your response, your returned object contains only one (malformed) *string*, not an array of objects. You can check this using http://jsonlint.com

How did you create the response? It should look more like:

```
{ "Addresses" : [{ 
        "Building":"Megatron Skyscraper",
        "BuldingId":1998,
        "AccountId":2000,
        "Number":7,
        "Name":"Megatron"
        },{
        "Building":"StarScream Skyscraper",
        "BuldingId":1999,
        "AccountId":2001,
        "Number":8,
        "Name":"StarScream"
}]}
```

**Update:** those leading zeros in `"Number":007` and `"Number":008` may cause problems, because they will be interpreted as octal values. I've removed them in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I created the response like so  "response.getWriter().write(json.toString());" with json being a JSONObject. I've tried searching for a JSONObject.write() method but my one does not contain such a method - any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @majestica: I don't know, ask a new question for that (or look for questions about creating a JSON string in your server side language, it probably has been asked before), as you now know why you can't access your property on the *client* side. I don't recognize/know that server side language.

Comment: Hi Marcel: heres a link to the server side code that shows how I am building my JSON:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154845/returning-json-response-from-servlet-to-javascript-jsp-page

Appreciate any advice you can give

Comment: That response you posted is exactly how I want it to look, but cannot seem to get that working

Answer (score 0):

Your response is valid but Addresses is a string and not an array.  The quotes shouldn't be there if it is to be treated like an array.  You could hack it a bit if you wanted and do

`address = JSON.parse(addresses.Addresses);`

Comment: Hi John, this is how I am building my JSON response:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154845/returning-json-response-from-servlet-to-javascript-jsp-page

Should I be taking a different approach?

Comment: I recommend using GSON (google's java json library) which can turn any POJO into a JSON-encoded string that the client-side can use w/o any parsing.  Once you google GSON there should be plenty of examples to get you going.  Hope that helps.